# What does "抽象" in this sentence mean in English?

Tags: translation, simplified-characters

On Chinese social networks, "抽象" does not always mean "abstract"

For example, "这个视频太**抽象**了" actually means this video is kinda **funny** instead of "This video is so abstract"

Comment: I think it is asking how 抽象 means funny in certain social networks

Comment: There's much more to the word 抽象 than just "funny". 抽象文化 is quite difficult to pin down, but it relates to online trash talk, a style of writing where individual Chinese characters are replaced with emojis, some very widespread memes and the online personalities behind them, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Using a stand-in word is not new.

For example:

- "gay" in "It is so gay" implies "ridiculous" when the speaker and his audience consider gayness to be something to poke fun of
- "cool" in "He is so cool" takes the meaning of "cool" as "calm" and extends it to mean "stylish"

Using 抽象 (abstract) as a stand-in word for "funny" sounds logical to people who associate "abstract drawing" with "childish doodle" (小孩塗鴉).

Many people consider childish things are funny, or things to be poked fun of

Answer (score 0):

More likely, here "抽象" is a caustic remark on the show for its lack of logic behind the story/performance. The real comment could be "不知所云" :)

Comment: it sounds logical to people who consider abstract = chaotic

Comment: @TangHo 他畫的佷抽像 = 我看不懂 :)

Comment: the remark can also be 莫名其妙

Comment: @TangHo "莫名其妙,不知所云" 經常是連用以表示對事物的輕篾及嘲諷 :) 用"抽象"一詞嘲弄人比較婉轉, 另人哭笑不得 :)